# CSS huge image as whole site background with responsiveness

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have 11_100px(height) x 3_840px(width) image that I want to fit on my website, I managed to somehow fit it for desktop size using the `padding-top` trick `calc(height / width * 100%)` to calculate aspect ratio). But when resizing viewport it becomes impossible to maintain for tablet and mobile.

Somehow I need to make the height fully reliable to the width size

I wasn't able to find any stack overflow sufficient answer, how are such large backgrounds handled for all devices?

**Example:** [link to my example](https://prnt.sc/256cttu)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is by adding a background image to a div.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/500x500.png?text=Placeholder");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: But the height of 100vh is insufficient, as I mentioned, the height of the background is 11100px

Comment: It should work with a 11100px  height too

Comment: i added link to my question for clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can define a background-image for `body`to which you apply the below settings (except using your own image of course).

The background image will *not* scroll with the content in this case - I suppose this is what you want.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1200/1600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: i added link to my question for clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this to scale the image to fit the width of the screen and if the width is too long it will be hidden.

```css
body {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/1200/1600");
  background-size: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

footer {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```